# Is a discrete graphics card mandatory?

Tags: 11.04, unity, graphics

I have a old intel o4 machine without graphics card. Still now I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 I would like to install Ubuntu 11.4 version. Would that require graphics card support?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "graphics card" you probably mean "discrete graphics card" as opposed to "integrated graphics card". There is no requirement at all to have discrete one.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Depends.

You can run the Classic Ubuntu Session at the very least - you might not be able to run Unity, the new desktop interface. To find out if it can, please take a look at this question - [How do I know if my video card can run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34579/how-do-i-know-if-my-video-card-can-run-unity) - it'll have to answers that you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tried to do the install without a graphics card, I've run several machines where I used the serial port as main terminal. Lately I configure my virtual machines (that use KVM) in such a way that I can use the virtual serial port to connect to them in case of emergency (like a network failure). This works fine.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13106/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-headless-machine) points to some help for headless installs.

I assume here that you're going to use the system as a headless server. Correct? In that case you needn't worry about the Unity interface etc. 
Or do you want to run desktop applications through SSH? In that case I totally depends on the CPU power and RAM of the machine you're talking about.