# How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, headless, remastersys

I need a CD or USB stick, that will install Ubuntu on a completely headless machine. Stick CD in and restart, no keyboard or screen should be involved.

There are a few obstacles:

1. The language selection menu when you first boot the CD.
2. The fact that the CD menu waits.
3. The installer's asking questions during installation.

Comment: Usefull link: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html

Comment: So I did this. however with the new kickstart iso when I restart my ubunutu server I get the following error ubuntu failed to load file amd-ucode/microcode_amd.bin I tried to search for the file on my "regularly" installed ubunutu-server but I couldn't find it.. and I don't get the error message when I reboot it

Comment: For Ubuntu **Desktop** look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts. The answer below wont work (and its unattributed source is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/932249/795299)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The complete solution is:

Remaster a CD, ie, download a non graphical ubuntu installation ISO (server or alternate installation CD), mount it

```
$ sudo su -
# mkdir -p /mnt/iso
# mount -o loop ubuntu.iso /mnt/iso
```

Copy the relevant files to a different directory

```
# mkdir -p /opt/ubuntuiso
# cp -rT /mnt/iso /opt/ubuntuiso
```

Prevent the language selection menu from appearing

```
# cd /opt/ubuntuiso
# echo en >isolinux/lang
```

Use GUI program to add a kickstart file named `ks.cfg`

```
# apt-get install system-config-kickstart
# system-config-kickstart # save file to ks.cfg
```

To add packages for the installation, add a `%package` section to the `ks.cfg` kickstart file, append to the end of `ks.cfg` file something like this.

```
%packages
@ ubuntu-server
openssh-server
ftp
build-essential
```

This will install the ubuntu-server "bundle", and will add the `openssh-server`, `ftp` and `build-essential` packages.

Add a preseed file, to suppress other questions

```
# echo 'd-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition \
select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm boolean true' > ks.preseed
```

Set the boot command line to use the kickstart and preseed files

```
# vi isolinux/txt.cfg
```

Search for

```
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
```

add `ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` and `preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed` to the append line. You can remove the `quiet` and `vga=788` words. It should look like

```
  append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed \
     initrd=/install/initrd.gz \
     ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --
```

Now create a new iso

```
# mkisofs -D -r -V "ATTENDLESS_UBUNTU" \
     -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
     -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 \
     -boot-info-table -o /opt/autoinstall.iso /opt/ubuntuiso
```

That's it. You'll have a CD that would install an Ubuntu system once you boot from it, without requiring a single keystroke.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, very useful! I found however that one doesn't need to specify the preseed file, just the filled in ks.cfg file was enough (also specified the partitions etc in there through kickstart). [ubuntu 10.04 64bit]

Comment: @symaedr the source dir was missing in the mkisofs line, since I assumed you're running mkisofs from the root directory of the unpacked Ubuntu CD. Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: I still seem to need to press enter when it boots up.

Comment: To bypass the need to press enter on boot change the timeout value from 0 to 10 in `/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`: timeout 10 Note that a value of 10 represents 1 second.

Comment: Make sure copy the .disk folder from the CD or iso. Otherwise, you will get 'Incorrect CD-ROM detected' error

Comment: I like the `isolinux/lang` setting, thank you.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but can I use this steps to create a bootable USB for ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @Manatax it should theoretically work. But why won't you try out and report the result for us here?

Comment: This works fine for me with Ubuntu 14.04 and it boots in a virtual machine. However, using dd to write the image to a USB stick results in an unbootable usb stick. I was able to get it to work with unetbootin but there are issues with unetbootin that make me have to manually add files.

Comment: `echo en >isolinux/lang`

No longer produces any result, (if it ever did, typo?) Merely reports: "-su: isolinux/lang: No such file or directory". Yes I mounted the ISO and copied the files from the loop to a new directory that I'm using to modify the files.

Comment: I see now that isolinux used to be a directory, whereas in 14.04 mini.iso it no longer exists. Maybe it needs created and that is the purpose of the command?

Comment: To install from a USB stick, you just need one more step to convert the ISO to a USB drive bootable format: `# isohybrid path/to/image.iso`

Comment: `lang` still exists in 18.04, it just has a new name. Try this: `echo en > isolinux/langlist`

Comment: original source found in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/932249/795299

Comment: Is this procedure still valid for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: See you in another 10 years when I am more confident with this kind of stuff!

Answer (score 6):

The instructions at this question cover the process for creating an EFI bootable ISO (like the official Ubuntu x86_64 ISO).:

[How do I create an EFI-bootable ISO of a customized version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457528/how-do-i-create-an-efi-bootable-iso-of-a-customized-version-of-ubuntu)

The key differences are setting this as the preseed file:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label     boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition            select  finish
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite         boolean true
d-i partman/confirm                     boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device  boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm       boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm                 boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite     boolean true
d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition       select      Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM
d-i partman/choose_partition                select      Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman-auto-lvm/no_boot            boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md         boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm                  boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite      boolean true
```

Use this as the kickstart file:

```
lang en_US
langsupport en_US
keyboard us
mouse
timezone America/Los_Angeles
rootpw --disabled
user USERNAME --fullname "USERNAME" --password "PASSWORD"
reboot
text
install
cdrom
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
firewall --disabled 
skipx
%packages
@ ubuntu-server
openssh-server
```

Edit the grub EFI boot configuration for the ISO:

```
sudo nano ~/ubuntu/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Set to:

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/light-blue
set menu_color_highlight=light-blue/light-gray
set timeout=10
set default=0

menuentry "Automatically Install Ubuntu Server with Custom Config" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet oem-config/enable=true --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Multiple server install with MAAS" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  modules=maas-enlist-udeb vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  MENU=/bin/cdrom-checker-menu quiet --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Rescue a broken system" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  rescue/enable=true --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
```

Set isolinux/txt.cfg like this:

```
default install
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server with Custom Config
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --
label cloud
  menu label ^Multiple server install with MAAS
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   modules=maas-enlist-udeb vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   MENU=/bin/cdrom-checker-menu vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

Create a dual boot catalog ISO:

```
sudo mkisofs -U -A "Custom1404" -V "Custom1404" -volset "Custom1404" -J -joliet-long -r -v -T -o ../Custom1404.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot .
```

Verify an EFI-bootable ISO has been created:

```
dumpet -i Custom1404.iso
```

Outputs:

```
Validation Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    ID: ""
    Checksum: 0x55aa
    Key bytes: 0x55aa
Boot Catalog Default Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 4 (0x0004)
    Load LBA: 3100 (0x00000c1c)
Section Header Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x91 (Final Section Header Entry)
    PlatformId: 0xef (EFI)
    Section Entries: 1
    ID: ""
Boot Catalog Section Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load address: 0 (0x0000)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 4672 (0x1240)
    Load LBA: 1932 (0x0000078c)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a shell script which performs this procedure, thanks for the introduction: [http://www.utech.de/2013/05/shell-script-creating-a-cd-for-unattended-ubuntu-server-installations/](http://web.archive.org/web/20140316120853/http://www.utech.de/2013/05/shell-script-creating-a-cd-for-unattended-ubuntu-server-installations)

The script you find following the link basically implements the procedure that @Elazar described, so the essential parts are just a screen above. I added the link to save somebody some time, and to make it a bit easier to repeat this for other versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I see. The script you find following the link basically implements the procedure that Elazar described, so the essential parts are just a screen above. I added the link to save somebody some time, and to make it a bit easier to repeat this for other versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please add the explanation from your comment to your answer.

Comment: Link seems to be broken.

Comment: Where is the script now?

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple method is described at the following link to an answer at AskUbuntu,

[How can I make a bootable, unattended USB restore disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930233/how-can-i-make-a-bootable-unattended-usb-restore-disk/930489#930489)

- *Create the system that you want* with portable network connection, for example according to

  - [Unmanaged Wired Network](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall#Unmanaged_Wired_Network) or
  - [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)
- *Make a [compressed] dd-image file* of the system (I think this is easier than remastering).
- *Make a shellscript and call it via 'autostart' in a persistent live system* according to [this description](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930233/how-can-i-make-a-bootable-unattended-usb-restore-disk/930489#930489). You can do it with minimal modifications (maybe match only the name of the compressed image file), or you can modify it to fit your particular case.