# Unattended install without swap

Tags: installation, kickstart

I'm following the instructions at [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-completely-unattended-install-for-ubuntu) to create an unattended install. This will be installed on a VM, so I would like to disable swap.

If I just create the kickstart file without any mention of swap, after completing the file system step, it stalls on a screen asking whether I'm sure I want to continue without swap and I have to confirm this.

Is there any way to disable swap in the method I'm using? If not, is there a different recommended method for unattended installs ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu (tested):

```
preseed --owner partman-basicfilesystems partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
```

For more details see:
http://tech.mariusb.com/2009/programming/debian-preseed-with-no-swap.html