# Where is a list of available package groups for kickstart?

Tags: kickstart

Due to (very) long-time bug in `system-config-kickstart`, the package selection section does not list available packages, one has to edit the `ks.cfg`: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-completely-unattended-install-for-ubuntu) explains how.

An example given in the question is

```
%packages
@ ubuntu-server
openssh-server
ftp
build-essential
```

I'm assuming `@ ubuntu-server` is a package group.  Where can I find this group name and other available package group names that can be added to the `%packages` section?

If I leave the `%packages` section completely blank, what gets installed? Nothing?

Comment: I tried `@ ubuntu-desktop` but kickstart doesn't install the Ubuntu Desktop group. The individual packages specified in ks.cfg did get installed though. PS: you can see the package groups with `tasksel --list-tasks`

Answer (score 5):

You can see the package groups with `tasksel --list-tasks`, and `tasksel` will allow you to choose which group to install.

This is the list of [meta packages in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages)

Listed in the URL are:

- gnome-desktop-environment
- kde
- kde-base
- xfce
- edubuntu-desktop
- edubuntu-server
- kubuntu-desktop
- ubuntu-desktop
- ubuntu-minimal
- ubuntu-restricted-extras
- ubuntu-standard
- xubuntu-desktop
- lubuntu-desktop
- linux-generic
- linux-headers-generic
- linux-image-generic
- linux-restricted-modules-generic
- language-support-*

Comment: Hmm please do not just insert links. Links (even the Ubuntu WIKI page) get deleted, moved to a new name. Besides that: these names are indeed some(!) meta packages but at least "ubuntu-server" is missing from the page.

Comment: Ah sorry I was in a hurry and can't give more details. In the comment section to the question I gave the commands that shows the meta packages. Will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu refers to the Redhat documentation in their wiki and according to [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html) and [CentOS documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-packageselection.html)...

> Refer to the `variant/repodata/comps-*.xml` file on the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Installation DVD for a list of groups
>
> Specify groups, one entry to a line, starting with an @ symbol, a space, and then the full group name or group id as given in the `comps.xml` file.

---

> If I leave the %packages section completely blank, what gets installed? Nothing?

No, Core and Base groups are always selected by default. And you need to include `--no-base` to install a minimal system.

---

Taken from the 2 links I can provide you a few groups:

- @ X Window System
- @ Desktop
- @ Sound and Video
- @ Graphical Internet
- @ GNOME Desktop Environment

(no guarantee these work with Ubuntu though)

Comment: Thanks for the info -- will investigate how  Ubuntu kickstart is resolving group names -- I had searched prior to posting the q. for `comps.xml`, but I'm unable to locate it in Ubuntu ks.

Comment: it is probably comps-{something_else}.xml. I failed to find it on a RHEL install too...