# Ubuntu 14 LTS install via PXE using ks.cfg - No unity after install

Tags: pxe, apt-cache, kickstart

I am trying to setup a PXE server with a ks.cfg to automate install. I have an apt-cache based repo. This is to serve as a host for nearly 200 machines.

The installation goes fine, but at the end, when the client machine reboots, it ends up in command line, without Unity Shell. I find that unity shell is not installed.

I downloaded the netboot.tar.gz from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/ and used tftpboot and apache to serve the contents.

Following is my ks.cfg file content.

```
lang en_IN
langsupport en_IN
keyboard us
mouse
timezone --utc Asia/Kolkata
rootpw --iscrypted xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
user iiit --fullname "xxxx" --iscrypted --password xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
reboot

#Use text mode install
#text

install

#Use Web installation
# I use the following in preseed file for using an apt-cache repo
# d-i mirror/http/proxy string http://10.0.1.95:3142

bootloader --location=mbr 
zerombr yes
clearpart --all --initlabel 
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size 514 
part / --fstype ext4 --size 20485 
part swap --size 4098 
part /var --fstype ext4 --size 15365 
part /home --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow 
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --hostname=lab-system
firewall --disabled 
skipx
%packages
aptitude
openssh-server
build-essential
vim
gcc
```

I have commented out the text option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kickstart config which we used to apply had this at the end:

```
%packages
@ Ubuntu Desktop
```

This notation is for tasks and package groups, from what I can make of [Where is a list of available package groups for kickstart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277557/where-is-a-list-of-available-package-groups-for-kickstart)

So include a line like:

```
@ Ubuntu Desktop
```

or

```
@ ubuntu-desktop
```

in your kickstart file.