# How to configuring which Packages should be removed on Ubuntu Installation?

Tags: installation, package-management, configuration

On Ubuntu installation not all packages on Live Session (*Try Ubuntu*) were installed on the Ubuntu,some are removed.

How i can configure which packages should be removed on an installation ?

(Example : I want to keep GParted from Live Session and not removed on Installation)

Comment: customize the ubuntu live disk.

Comment: Then,how i can do that ? which part of the Live disk should i configure ?

Comment: did you want to customize `try ubuntu` `install ubuntu` options on the startup.

Comment: I think no,it seems what i want to configure is the installer.Especially the part which configuring what packages should be removed from Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the installer (the ISO) is a LOT of work (look at my and other answers here in how messy this can get: [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679) )  It is also one-time only so you will need to do this with every new release.

For adding software during installation have a look at "[kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility)". It is not 100% supported by Ubuntu but you can add a seed file. [Example file](https://gist.github.com/ludo/3652811).
Here are some tips: [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu) You can create a config file for adding software. Last time I used this it did NOT have a method on how to remove packages.

A working kickstart file can be re-used when a new release arrives. But it is also a pain to setup correctly (to test you must install with the kickstart file and failure means you wasted a lot of time).

But there is an easier method: you can add gParted to your installation after installation. Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

I have a post-installation script with lots of package names in it that I run after installation. It is the best method to configuring your system to what you want. I myself always install mysql, smplayer, vlc and shutter. All I do is execute a text file with lots of 'apt-get's in the file.

This is something you can repeat after every install and it requires the least amount of maintenance. Pseudo example:

sudo apt-get install vlc
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   sudo apt-get remove totem

Save it, make it executable, run it after the installation and all you need to do is provide the password 1 time and it will install/remove all you added to the text file.

I have played alot with creating my own ISO installer, played with kickstart but none of them come as close as just a plain text file with some apt-gets in it.

Comment: Thankyou.maybe i looking answer like this.But my freq of re-installing is somwehow high and re-installing stuff after re-installing the Ubuntu will cost a lot of bandwitdh.

Comment: Partly true: if you include the DVD as a source it will 1st search the DVD and can save a bit of downloading. BUT ... you will need to update your system afterwards and that will eat your bandwidth regardless of the extra software. I would advice to limit re-installing (ie. only use the LTS). Or get someone to send you a DVD by snail mail :D