# How do I create an EFI-bootable ISO of a customized version of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, uefi, custom-distributions

I have created an own Ubuntu distribution that I want to boot (from a USB) on my MAC.

When using the standard 64bit-Ubuntu-iso from the Ubuntu website, it boots. However, when doing the exact same thing with the iso file containing my own distribution it does not work, and it appears to only support legacy boot. However, the OS has the /sys/firmware/efi folder, so I know it supports EFI. I made the iso using Relinux.

I have looked at the differences between the two ISO files, and have seen that the standard ubuntu has an EFI/BOOT folder containing grubx64.efi and BOOTx64.EFI, and also has a boot folder which doesn't exist in the other. I have tried to copy these two directories, the EFI and boot folder into my other USB, but doesn't work.

My question is:

- How can I get these two folders into my current iso file?
- And how can I make an iso of my distribution so that it supports EFI boot?

Answer (score 18):

You need to make a dual boot catalog ISO so that it will boot EFI and MBR. The standard Ubuntu 14.04 x64 ISO file works this way but there are no instructions available to make a new 14.04 bootable ISO for EFI systems. I was able to piece together the right steps to create an ISO like this.

These instructions will let you create a custom Ubuntu 14.04 Server ISO that can boot EFI and MBR. When EFI booting on a system with a blank, uninitialized disk (for example on a new Generation 2 VM in Hyper-V), setup will start automatically, then automatically wipe the disk and install the base ubuntu-server packages and OpenSSH. This is designed for automatically provisioning new systems with Ubuntu 14.04 using LVM and auto-partitioning. If you use this ISO on an existing Linux system then the installer will stop when it detects existing disks and wait for input. If you use this ISO on a non-EFI system (for example a Generation 1 Hyper-V VM) then it will wait at the graphical installer startup screen and require input before continuing to the auto installer.

The result is a base Ubuntu Server installation with ubuntu-server and openssh-server only.

Here are the steps to create an EFI-bootable ISO:

Get the 14.04 ISO:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
```

Mount it and extract its contents to a new folder:

```
sudo mkdir -p ~/iso
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso.iso ~/iso
sudo mkdir ~/ubuntu
sudo cp -rT ~/iso ~/ubuntu
```

Change into the directory where we will be doing our work:

```
cd ~/ubuntu
```

Set the language to English:

```
sudo -i
echo en >/home/user/ubuntu/isolinux/lang
exit
```

Create a preseed file that will use LVM to auto-partition the disk using all available space:

```
sudo nano ~/ubuntu/ks.preseed
```

Replace the file contents with this:

```
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label     boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition            select  finish
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite         boolean true
d-i partman/confirm                     boolean true
d-i partman-auto/purge_lvm_from_device  boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm       boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm                 boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite     boolean true
d-i partman-auto/init_automatically_partition       select      Guided - use entire disk and set up LVM
d-i partman/choose_partition                select      Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman-auto-lvm/no_boot            boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md         boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm                  boolean true
d-i partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite      boolean true
```

Create a kickstart file that will configure Ubuntu during the installation: (make sure you change the username part, and you should use encrypted passwords)

```
sudo nano ~/ubuntu/ks.cfg
```

Replace the file contents with this:

```
lang en_US
langsupport en_US
keyboard us
mouse
timezone America/Los_Angeles
rootpw --disabled
user USERNAME --fullname "USERNAME" --password "PASSWORD"
reboot
text
install
cdrom
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
firewall --disabled 
skipx
%packages
@ ubuntu-server
openssh-server
```

Edit the grub configuration file so when the ISO performs an EFI boot the bootloader uses the right options to use our preseed and configuration files:

```
sudo nano ~/ubuntu/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Replace the file contents with this:

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/light-blue
set menu_color_highlight=light-blue/light-gray
set timeout=10
set default=0

menuentry "Automatically Install Ubuntu Server with Custom Config" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed quiet oem-config/enable=true --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Multiple server install with MAAS" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  modules=maas-enlist-udeb vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  MENU=/bin/cdrom-checker-menu quiet --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
menuentry "Rescue a broken system" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /install/vmlinuz  rescue/enable=true --
    initrd  /install/initrd.gz
}
```

Edit the isolinux boot menu for non-EFI booting (MBR booting) to use the custom config and custom preseed:

```
sudo nano ~/ubuntu/isolinux/txt.cfg
```

Replace the file contents with this:

```
default install
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server with Custom Config
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --
label cloud
  menu label ^Multiple server install with MAAS
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   modules=maas-enlist-udeb vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
label check
  menu label ^Check disc for defects
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append   MENU=/bin/cdrom-checker-menu vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
label memtest
  menu label Test ^memory
  kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
  menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
  localboot 0x80
```

Create the ISO:

This command is a modified version of the command shown at http://petersmithphotog.no-ip.biz/wiki/index.php/Unattended_Install. Those instructions do not work for Ubuntu 14.04 because they point to the wrong locations for the file efi.img. (should be in ./boot/grub/ on the ISO)

```
sudo mkisofs -U -A "Custom1404" -V "Custom1404" -volset "Custom1404" -J -joliet-long -r -v -T -o ../Custom1404.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot .
```

Verify the ISO has the correct style boot catalogs:

The original ISO you downloaded from Ubuntu:

```
dumpet -i ~/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
```

Output:

```
Validation Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    ID: ""
    Checksum: 0x55aa
    Key bytes: 0x55aa
Boot Catalog Default Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 4 (0x0004)
    Load LBA: 8446 (0x000020fe)
Section Header Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x91 (Final Section Header Entry)
    PlatformId: 0xef (EFI)
    Section Entries: 1
    ID: ""
Boot Catalog Section Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load address: 0 (0x0000)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 4672 (0x1240)
    Load LBA: 24754 (0x000060b2)
```

The new ISO you created:

```
dumpet -i ~/Custom1404.iso
```

Output:

```
Validation Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    ID: ""
    Checksum: 0x55aa
    Key bytes: 0x55aa
Boot Catalog Default Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 4 (0x0004)
    Load LBA: 3100 (0x00000c1c)
Section Header Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x91 (Final Section Header Entry)
    PlatformId: 0xef (EFI)
    Section Entries: 1
    ID: ""
Boot Catalog Section Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load address: 0 (0x0000)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 4672 (0x1240)
    Load LBA: 1932 (0x0000078c)
```

You can compare this output to the output you get from an ISO constructed using the instructions at [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu): (they create an MBR only ISO, not an dual boot catalog ISO)

```
sudo mkisofs -D -r -V "non-efi-ubuntu" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o ../non-efi-ubuntu.iso .
```

Get ISO info:

```
dumpet -i ~/non-efi-ubuntu.iso
```

Output:

```
Validation Entry:
    Header Indicator: 0x01 (Validation Entry)
    PlatformId: 0x00 (80x86)
    ID: ""
    Checksum: 0x55aa
    Key bytes: 0x55aa
Boot Catalog Default Entry:
    Entry is bootable
    Boot Media emulation type: no emulation
    Media load segment: 0x0 (0000:7c00)
    System type: 0 (0x00)
    Load Sectors: 4 (0x0004)
    Load LBA: 1925 (0x00000785)
```

Comment: While a very detailed answer, this looks like it does a lot more than simply creatable an EFI bootable ISO. Is preseeding and kickstart necessary? If they are, why not use only one? AFAIK, preseeding can cover everything kickstart does.

Comment: It does do more than create an EFI bootable ISO. By removing the kickstart and preseed options from these instructions you can create a standard Ubuntu 14.04 ISO. The specific changes have been noted in the answer.

Comment: Then I request you to keep only the relevant sections here, since you already have an answer on the unattended installation question with everything else.

Comment: YES! I been searching far and wide for a way to create an EFI bootable ISO from customized folder .. glad you put everything here in one place!

Comment: This works great in a virtual machine but I cannot boot this when copied to a USB drive like it does with the vanilla Ubuntu image.

Comment: Has anyone tried using the image with virt-manager ?

Comment: I had to add d-i preseed/early_command string umount /media

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel, To install from a USB stick, you just need one more step to convert the ISO to a USB drive bootable format: `# isohybrid path/to/image.iso`

Comment: For installation with UEFI, you can copy the iso content on a FAT32 usb stick. Then you can edit the files. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media/395880#395880

Answer (score 1):

## UEFI enabled USB Drive

If you want an Installation from USB Medium, you don't need to create a customized ISO first.

Creating UEFI-only booting USB live media is pretty straight forward. Just copy the files to your *FAT32-formatted* USB drive. **That's it!**
It will be detected as a valid UEFI Boot Medium.

Then you can modify the files directly on the USB Drive.

Source and Details: [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media/395880#395880)

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is:

1) create systemback live iso

```
sudo apt-get install systemback
sudo apt-get install live-boot
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge casper
```

2) add a uefi partition to the iso in this way:

```
cd /home
cat `ls -1 -t syst*.iso|head -1` efi.img >/tmp/live.iso
echo -e "n\np\n2\n\n\nt\n2\nef\nw\n"|fdisk /tmp/live.iso
```

3) copy the iso to media (in this case my pendrive in /dev/sdb

```
pv /tmp/live.iso | dd of=/dev/sdb conv=notrunc,noerror
```