# Create bootable usb from iso

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, live-usb

I have created a custom iso and I followed the instructions to make the iso from a wiki article from ubuntu with the following command:

```
mkisofs -D -r -V "CUSTOM_UBUNTU" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /tmp/ubuntu16-desktop-unattended-install.iso /opt/isodir
```

The iso does work, I tested on Oracle VM and I was able to boot from it, but when I created an image on a USB, I cannot boot from the usb at all. Did I miss something? how can I create the iso to be able to boot from the USB? is it missing some UEFI/EFI directives?

Comment: Really can not tell from what little you posted and support for custom .iso is limited at best.

Comment: I created the iso, it boots on Oracle VM but it wont boot from a USB flash drive for example, wonder if I missed an option or something or if UEFI/EFI does not recognize the format/options?

Comment: What error do you get? How did you set your BIOS? What sort of google search did you do ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/457528/how-do-i-create-an-efi-bootable-iso-of-a-customized-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: no errors, the iso can boot on oracle vm, I know how to create bootable usb images, I can install the original iso on a usb and run it on my laptop. Is just this custom iso that gave me problems, guess is missing something or the way mkisofs creates the iso, is not readable by a physical hardware.

Comment: I can not tell from what you have posted.

Comment: From https://askubuntu.com/questions/457528/how-do-i-create-an-efi-bootable-iso-of-a-customized-version-of-ubuntu `mkisofs -U -A "Custom1404" -V "Custom1404" -volset "Custom1404" -J -joliet-long -r -v -T -o ../Custom1404.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e boot/grub/efi.img -no-emul-boot`

Comment: You haven't noted two critical details: (1) How did you copy the `.iso` file to a USB flash drive, and (2) are you trying to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode or in EFI/UEFI mode? Depending on the answers to those questions, there may be others, like what (if anything) is in the `EFI/BOOT` directory on the resulting USB drive and what filesystem it uses. If you don't care about the `.iso` disc, then you're probably better off creating a bootable USB disk directly.