# Unattended installation

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, uck

I am planning to replace Windows XP based 100 odd desktops with Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop 32bit on my clients branches across the country. At my home location I would deploy it manually as I have team to do the stuff. But my clients branches dont have technical support personal. Desktops are in warranty so manufacturer takes care of any issues rest is handled remotely.

I wish to install a customized copy of ubuntu 12.04 with few select packages and external softwares in unattended mode via a usb or dvd rom sent to the branch offices. Wherein they will insert the dvd or usb and start the installation and they will get a ready made system. I will also send them a process document of how to assign IP address to the system so that I can take remote control and do rest of the things remaining.

I would like to know if this is possible in first place? I am checking Uck right now. Hope that helps.

Thanks in advance.

To an extent this is a duplicate question, the answers of the previous questions do satisfy my query of customizing the installer CD/USB but I am not able to get the preseeding stuff clearly from it. Especially if I have to include preseeding in my installer DVD/CD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) or may be [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/appendix-preseed.html) to manage this. The [example preseed file](http://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) contains most settings available along with comments describing their use. You can use local mirrors. The official documentation on the matter is detailed enough that I'm not sure if I should go about rewriting it here.

Comment: Yes Going through preseeding documents. Thanks.