# Steps to create a kickstart server on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kickstart

Need a step by step procedure for creating a kickstart server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

[This is a good step-by-step guide](https://archethought.wordpress.com/2015/03/29/ubuntu-bootable-usb-with-kickstart/)

> **TL;DR**; use isohybrid after repacking the custom iso
>
> To make this usb, I used a virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04
>   installed. The goal here is to make a bootable usb that doesn’t
>   require selection of things like keyboard layout, language, etc. We
>   want an automatic install of an Ubuntu server.
>
> We need to get the ubuntu image that we’re going to be customizing for
>   our installation.
>
> ```
> wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso
> ```
>
> We’re going to need a place to mount the unpacked iso file.
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /mnt/iso
> ```
>
> After we have created a mount point for it, now we have to mount it.
>   This will expose the files that are held inside the iso.
>   Unfortunately, the files will be read-only
>
> . sudo mount -o loop ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso /mnt/iso
>
> In order to modify the files, we need to copy them to a directory
>   where we can modify them, so we’ll create the directory and then copy
>   the files to it.
>
> ```
> sudo mkdir -p /opt/ubuntuiso
> sudo cp -rT /mnt/iso /opt/ubuntuiso
> ```
>
> Our new working directory will be /opt/ubuntuiso
>
> ```
> cd /opt/ubuntuiso
> ```
>
> In order to avoid being prompted for language selection in the
>   installation process, we need to tell it what language we’re going to
>   use. In this case, en is being used because I speak english.
>
> ```
> echo en | sudo tee isolinux/lang
> ```
>
> Now we are actually going to build the kickstart file with a program
>   called system-config-kickstart. So we make sure it’s installed and
>   then run it.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install system-config-kickstart
> system-config-kickstart
> ```
>
> Then save the file from the GUI in `/opt/ubuntuiso/`. This should save
>   a file called ks.cfg. My ks.cfg looks like the following
>
> ```
> #Generated by Kickstart Configurator
> #platform=AMD64 or Intel EM64T
> #System language
> lang en_US
> #Language modules to install
> langsupport en_US
> #System keyboard
> keyboard us
> #System mouse
> mouse
> #System timezone
> timezone America/Denver
> #Root password
> rootpw --disabled
> #Initial user
> user ubuntu --fullname "ubuntu" --iscrypted --password $1$MQ0zGB4W$pwjX8nolgr2RJch2Omamt.
> #Reboot after installation
> reboot
> #Use text mode install
> text
> #Install OS instead of upgrade
> install
> #Use CDROM installation media
> cdrom
> #System bootloader configuration
> bootloader --location=mbr
> #Clear the Master Boot Record
> zerombr yes
> #Partition clearing information
> clearpart --all --initlabel
> #Disk partitioning information
> part /boot --fstype ext2 --size 100 --asprimary
> part swap --recommended
> part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow
> #System authorization infomation
> auth --useshadow --enablemd5
> #Network information
> network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
> #Firewall configuration
> firewall --disabled
> #Do not configure the X Window System
> skipx
> %post
> #!/bin/bash
> exec < /dev/tty6 > /dev/tty6
> chvt 6
> echo 'Acquire::http { Proxy "http://10.2.4.27"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02proxy
> apt-get update
> apt-get -y upgrade
> apt-get -y dist-upgrade
> apt-get install -y git ansible openssh-server vim
> chvt 1
> ```
>
> There is a little bit of hijacking done in the postscript (everything
>   after `%post`). The line beginning with exec and the following line
>   (`chvt 6`) are forcing the installer show the output from the commands
>   that are run after that. The reason for this is that the loading bar
>   will not move during the installation, and it can appear as though the
>   installer has hung. The following line that does the proxy is for the
>   apt-cache on our local network. The final line (`chvt 1`) reverts the
>   output to the main installer.
>
> Now we need to add the preseed file so that we can avoid other
>   questions.
>
> ```
> echo 'd-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true d-i partman/choose_partition \ select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk d-i partman/confirm boolean true' | sudo tee ks.preseed
> ```
>
> Now we need to tell the installer about the files that we just saved,
>   so we need to modify isolinux/txt.cfg. First we need to make the file
>   writable.
>
> ```
> sudo chmod +w isolinux/txt.cfg
> ```
>
> Then we need to replace the append line of the following section
>
> ```
> label install
> menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
> kernel /install/vmlinuz
> append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
> ```
>
> Replace the append line with
>
> ```
> append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --
> ```
>
> Save and exit the file. We also need to make sure that we put the file
>   back in its original state, so remove the write permissions.
>
> ```
> sudo chmod -w isolinux/txt.cfg
> ```
>
> Now create the new iso file that we will use to create the bootable
>   usb.
>
> ```
> sudo mkisofs -D -r -V "ATTENDLESS_UBUNTU" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /opt/autoinstall.iso /opt/ubuntuiso
> ```
>
> In order to finalize the bootable iso for a usb, we need to hybridize
>   it.
>
> ```
> sudo isohybrid /opt/autoinstall.iso
> ```
>
> After hybridizing it, we can push it to the usb drive. The usb drive
>   in my virtual machine shows up in `/dev/sdb`, but you need to use the
>   correct label, so replace X accordingly Make sure that the usb drive
>   is unmounted.
>
> ```
> sudo umount /dev/sdX
> ```
>
> And finally push the iso onto the usb drive. (Please note **this
>   destroys data on the target device - make sure you know what you are
>   doing)
>
> ```
> sudo dd if=/opt/autoinstall.iso of=/dev/sdX
> ```
>
> Now your usb drive should be ready for installation!

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Especially in case the site ever goes down.

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution:

Remaster a CD, ie, download a non-graphical Ubuntu installation ISO (server or alternate installation CD) and mount it. In this case, your Ubuntu 14 ISO.

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/iso
sudo mount -o loop ubuntu.iso /mnt/iso
```

Copy the relevant files to a different directory

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/ubuntuiso
sudo cp -rT /mnt/iso /opt/ubuntuiso
```

Prevent the language selection menu from appearing

```
cd /opt/ubuntuiso
echo en | sudo tee isolinux/lang
```

Use GUI program to add a kickstart file named `ks.cfg`

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-kickstart
system-config-kickstart # save file to ks.cfg
```

To add packages for the installation, add a `%package` section to the `ks.cfg` kickstart file, append to the end of `ks.cfg` file something like this.

```
%packages
@ ubuntu-server
openssh-server
ftp
build-essential
```

This will install the ubuntu-server "bundle", and will add the `openssh-server`, `ftp` and `build-essential` packages.

Add a preseed file, to suppress other questions

```
echo 'd-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition \
select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i partman/confirm boolean true' | sudo tee ks.preseed
```

Set the boot command line to use the kickstart and preseed files

```
sudo nano isolinux/txt.cfg
```

Search for

```
label install
  menu label ^Install Ubuntu Server
  kernel /install/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
```

add `ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg` and `preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed` to the append line. You can remove the `quiet` and `vga=788` words. It should look like

```
append file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg preseed/file=/cdrom/ks.preseed --
```

Now create a new iso

```
sudo mkisofs -D -r -V "ATTENDLESS_UBUNTU" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /opt/autoinstall.iso /opt/ubuntuiso
```

That's it. You'll have a CD that would install an Ubuntu system once you boot from it, without requiring any input.

Tweak the ks.cfg and preseed files as needed.