# Ubuntu 16.04 unattended installation won't boot

Tags: system-installation, preseed

I've got two questions, which don't let me sleep, so I hope someone has a hint or solution for me. I try to run a 'simple' unattended Ubuntu 16.04 installation, because of the well known benefits.

What I did by now:

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 like the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts) tells me. I tried to run it in a VM and it works fine. So I tried it on a "real" device and it fails in many points:

1) Some devices detect my USB device but do not boot and run the installation. So I found [isohyprid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid) which solve this issue on most of our devices (Lenovo ThinkPads) but not on Asus or HP ones. I set up a bash script which does the iso for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create the iso file, excluding .git directory and this script

echo -e "A iso-file of this directory will be created in /tmp/ubuntu16-desktop-unattended-install.iso shortly."

SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )/

mkisofs -D -r -V "UNATTENDED_UBUNTU" -cache-inodes -J -l -exclude .git -exclude create_iso.sh -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o /tmp/ubuntu16-desktop-unattended-install.iso $SCRIPT_DIR

echo -e "done iso...\n Make it portable with isohybrid..."

isohybrid /tmp/ubuntu16-desktop-unattended-install.iso

echo -e "Done."
echo -e "\n\nUse \n\nsudo dd if=/tmp/ubuntu16-desktop-unattended-install.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M\n\nto put it to an USB stick"
```

Does someone has an idea, why the USB does not boot on some devices?

2) On those devices, which boot from USB, the unattended installation runs quite well. There is no questions to answer manually and no error which shows up - until the system reboots after installation. I get a black screen and the system don't boot, I don't see GRUB bootloader too.

My partitioning looks like this:

First part:

```
# Newer ubiquity command
ubiquity partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
ubiquity partman-auto/method string regular 
ubiquity partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
ubiquity partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
ubiquity partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic
```

Second part:

```
# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation
ubiquity partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
ubiquity partman/choose_partition select finish
ubiquity partman/confirm boolean true
ubiquity partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

User and network configuration follows and this is the last part:

```
## Grub
d-i grub-installer/grub2_instead_of_grub_legacy boolean true
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

If I comment the second part, I need to answer the questions manually but, the installation works/boots and runs as expected. 
I'm sure, the solution to fix my problem is somewhere hidden in this second part but I can't find it. Maybe an options is mission, but which one. I tried it with "ubiquity" and with "d-i" command but there is no obvious change.

Can someone help me to solve these two issues?