# Outfitting a self configuring bootable disk

Tags: boot

I am interested in a process that outfits a SSD to:

- boot up
- self-install configure 16.04 from files on the SSD

Is this possible?

If possible, is there a word to describe the idea of bootable disk that configures itself with an OS?

Unfortunately, [the question regarding unattended installation form CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts) is not quite what I am seeking.  The difference is that the finished SSD is shipped to another user to install in a desktop and the goal is for minimal setup work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts)

Comment: Maybe **Ubuntu OEM installation** would do what you want. See this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview