# What am I missing to automate my 18.04 install?

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, automation, preseed

I am trying to automate my install of Ubuntu 18.04. This is how my current boot paramters look like (forgive me but it's long)

```
boot=casper 
auto-install/enable=true 
console-setup/ask_detect=false 
console-setup/layoutcode=us 
debconf/frontend=noninteractive 
debian-installer=en_US.UTF-8 
debian-installer/language=en 
debian-installer/country=US 
debian-installer/locale=en_US.UTF-8 
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text 
fb=false 
grub-installer/bootdev=/dev/sda 
hostname=vagrant 
initrd=/casper/initrd.lz 
kbd-chooser/method=us 
keyboard-configuration/modelcode=SKIP keyboard-configuration/layout=USA keyboard- 
configuration/variant=USA locale=en_US.UTF-8 netcfg/get_domain=vm 
netcfg/get_hostname=vagrant noapic 
preseed/url=http://localhost:3000/preseed-18.04-desktop.cfg ---
```

Note that the preseed file can be found if I access via link. After I type this in, I get presented with the usual welcome splash screen [image: Ubuntu Splash screen]

I don't understand what I am missing because I think I followed everything in [the preseeding installation guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs02.html) as well as the [Boot parameters section](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch05s03.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 desktop seems to be based on *ubiquity* installer instead of *debian-installer*. I'm currently also trying to create an automated install and I see two possible things on your installation:

- You lack `automated-ubiquity` as a boot parameter. I assume `auto-install/enable=true` is a long version of `auto=true`
- The entries of the preseed file start with `d-i` instead of `ubiquity`. It seems the *ubiquity* installer don't look for some `d-i` keys..

You can take a look at this question: [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts)
But I have notice that on 18.04 desktop changes the prefix of the preseed keys from `d-i` to `ubiquity`.