# Unattended install with packages

Tags: apt

I am trying to automate the install of Ubuntu Desktop, along with some packages (which will have dependencies that would also need to be included). The catch is that the target system will be offline, with no access to remote apt repositories. I created an unattended install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 Desktop, following [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts). Then, I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.neteye-blog.com/2018/06/custom-ubuntu-iso-image-for-unattended-and-offline-installation/) to get a local apt repository baked into the .iso, with no luck - many steps seemed to be skipped in the tutorial. Has anyone had any luck doing something like this before, or would I be better off trying to clone an existing online ubuntu instance with all of the packages installed already?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for cloning software? I am close to where I want to be with preseeding, but cannot seem to get the packages in /pool/extras to be visible to the OS. I followed the "Offline Installation" section here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/409607/how-to-create-a-customized-ubuntu-server-iso

When I 'sudo apt install <package>', I get 'E: Package X has no installation candidate'

Comment: I discovered my issue. I needed to add my local repository to the /etc/apt/sources.list file like this:

deb [trusted=yes] file:<path/to/local/repo> ./

Comment: Wonderful! You should add that as a real Answer (it is) so folks in the future can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my issue. I needed to add my local repository to the /etc/apt/sources.list file like this:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:<path/to/local/repo> ./
```

The way to do this with preseeding was to add this to the preseed file:

```
d-i apt-setup/local0/repository string deb [trusted=yes] file:/opt/extras ./
```