# Lubuntu 18.04: Unattended install

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

I'm trying to create an USB stick to install Lubuntu 18.04 completely unattended on machines without display. Most importantly, I want to install openssh-server during installation.
I found the following documentation: [Automating the installation using preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apb.html). But I think the description is somewhat incomplete. 
After following the tutorial at [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts), which is aimed at 16.04, I was able to automatically start the install process. However, during installation the account setup is incomplete and after the reboot I get stuck in a bootloop.

Could anybody provide me any resources or additional information on how to setup an unattended install on lubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I want Lubuntu desktop because I want to have the option to connect with VNC.
I assume sudo apt install openssh-server is enough to connect to a machine in my lan. What kind of configuration do you mean?
Actually, my goal is to prepare the machine for ansible. openssh-server is a requirement to run a ansible script from remote.