# Making Automated Installation USB on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, usb

I'm going to install Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on 64 real machines.

I followed this guide and It worked well on virtual machine.(although that is for 16.04)

[How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820)

But when I tried this on real machine with USB, It does boot, but It proceed normal install step. (not automated)

I'm assuming `append file=/cdrom/ks.preseed` part on .cfg is a matter because definitely I'm using USB instead of CD/DVD.

So I have tried several times that changing path to 'ks.preseed', '/ks.preseed', './ks.preseed', '/dev/sda/ks.preseed', /dev/sda1/ks.preseed' and all try has failed.

Time is flowing and I installed manually on 4 machines in a hurry. and now I still have 60 empty machines.

Any advice or help gonna be appreciated. Many thanks for reading this.

Comment: Welcome, would you be willing to try another approach? That said, if the machines are in a network.

Comment: maybe it does.  please inform me

Comment: In similar situations I used [drbl](https://drbl.org/). It maybe complicated to make it work, it has a steep learning curve. But once you handle it well enough, you make an image of one machine and clone it to all the rest. A plus is that you can configure the image (an installed OS) as you like, and that configuation will be cloned to the other machines. Of course, take this a suggestion.

Comment: I'm not sure this case is proper for me because I need individual 64 disk but I'll discuss this with my senior tomorrow.(now I'm off) and your advise inspired me about network preseed path. Many thanks for giving consideration.

Comment: You may want to see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1219449/453950). It links to a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for advise of another method! Time is still chasing and I'm doing another work for now. I'll add result asap.