# Creating a custom Ubuntu Server (Minimal Install) ISO which only asks for disk and hostname during installation

Tags: server, bash, system-installation

I'm in need of creating a custom minimal install iso. When booting this ISO all I need is the user to select what disk to use and hostname. Nothing else, we managed to do this using kickstart pre-script on CentOS but we'd like to know how to do it in Ubuntu? Cloud-Init seems really limited and unfinished.

What we'd like it do do on boot from iso:

- Ask which HDD to install (We'll configure it to use full HDD so must be able to do that)
- Ask what hostname to set to the system

While installing it needs to do:

- Add 3 users with 3 different password and groups.
- Add a script to one of the users home directory which will run at login (bash script) where the user can continue the installation (add packages e.t.c.) we already have that script.

Is this possible in Ubuntu's current state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts) (This applies to server as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You need create an ISO with an "unattended installation"

Check this solution: [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts)

Comment: This is correct, but in this case the OP should be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: This is an "Unattended" installation, I want attended where they must supply the disk they want to install to and hostname? Currently on CentOS image we have they do:

1. Supply software to install
2. Supply disk to install on
3. Supply hostname to setup

Then we automatically install all the 3 and setup vpn's and stuff like that. But we want to convert to Ubuntu which proves to be harder than expected :)

Also it seems like preseed is not the usage for 20.04?