# Install Ubuntu Server over SSH?

Tags: server, ssh

So I got my laptop with a broken monitor and defect keyboard that sometimes just doesn't want to use an external monitor. I have Debian 8 running on it (don't ask how I managed to install it) and I'm able to connect to it via SSH. Is it somehow possible to nuke everything and install Ubuntu server on it? I have physical access and could power cycle it but I won't be able to see anything on the monitor.

Comment: [This may help you ](https://askubuntu.com/a/122506/260379)