# Ubuntu auto-install USB doesn't boot

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, preseed

I am currently trying to do a completely unattended Ubuntu install with [preseed](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apb.html), following AskUbuntu [automated install instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/806820/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-desktop-16-04-1-lts).

Everything works fine on VirtualBox (I am simulating a DVD) but when I try to burn my ISO on a USB stick and boot it on a computer ([UP Squared](http://www.up-board.org/upsquared/) with  Intel CPU), it doesn't boot !

I'd like to add : I have no problem with my bootable key when using a standard ubuntu installation. On the discussion I linked above, best answers says to "burn it on a DVD". Is there a difference between a burn DVD and a bootable USB key ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you treat your iso file with `isohybrid` to make it a hybrid iso file? In that case it should work to **clone** it to a working USB boot drive. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid).

Comment: Maybe the method of the following link can help, [How can I make a bootable, unattended USB restore disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930233/how-can-i-make-a-bootable-unattended-usb-restore-disk/930489?s=9|6.1027#930489)

Comment: @sudodus isohybrid seem to do the trick ! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sudodus pointed out, I needed to treat my iso with [isohybrid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid).

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask how you burned your ISO? If you used Unetbootin by any chance, it might be possible that the liveUSB has no boot flag.This [bug](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/issues/112) has been around for a while. And if the liveUSB isn't recognised as bootable... it doesn't boot.

You can solve this with GParted. Select the USB drive, and do a right click. A menu will open which holds "Manage flags". If you click that another menu opens, where you can select "boot". After you've done this, close GParted and (re)boot from the liveUSB.

Comment: Hi  ! Thanks for your answer. I simply used Startup Disk Creator (USB-creator).