# Unattended install i am a noob

Tags: server, system-installation

I am trying to install unattendedly ubuntu server. I am using this tutorial:

- [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu#122506)

I do not understand in the post if i need to install kickstart ? Because when I type.

```
apt-get install system-config-kickstart
```

It is unable to find the package (i am on kali, but it doesn't change apt)
Help ?

Comment: Kali is not Ubuntu.  We don't support Kali here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to install kickstart

```
sudo apt install system-config-kickstart
```

To instal kickstart, you have to activate the universe software, by opening **software**, then click on the **menu software/updates**. On the Ubuntu Software tab **enable** *Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)*. Enter your password if asked for.

BTW: in this instruction **#** means that this command has to be used as sudo. So simple add **sudo** before the command, when you see a #.