# How to create an Unattended Install of Ubuntu Mate 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, unattended-upgrades

You are looking at the boot stick for [Ubuntu Mate 20.04](https://ubuntu-mate.org/). Plus a folder `frankscripts` containing a row of bash-scripts (to create multiple usersr, common folders, a bunch of chrome profiles, etc)

I wish to run those scripts as root after all else is done. (occasional user interaction like adding a password or two micht become necessary, but that's about it.

[image]

#### **How can I turn this into an unattend install?**

Booting from the stick, having everything done... (if possible, provide a script for my partitioning strategy, but just on a side note).

I did read the word `kickstart` in [some](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu) places.

But I still have no clue what to do and where to start... how to enter or hook into the installer, or extend it (in whichever ways Ubuntu-Mate does or allows this).

Comment: [This is what you want](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#storage)... It is not only for servers.

Comment: Hi @Raffa, `late commands` and indeed the [`(netboo) quickstart guide`](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart) sound interesting. Will look into it...Thanx!