# Ubuntu Server 18.04 preseed

Tags: 18.04, server, partitioning, disk, preseed

I want to create a preseed file that will automatically choose the disc (/dev/nvme0n1 or /dev/sda1) and create the partitions without approval.

So far, it is detected the disk, but I need to select "YES," and after that, I need to select "YES" for the partition (attached images).

```
    # -------- Partitioning --------
d-i partman/unmount_active                                  boolean     true
d-i partman-auto/disk                                       string      /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method                                     string      regular
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe                              select      atomic
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label            boolean     true
d-i partman/choose_partition                                select      finish
d-i partman/confirm                                         boolean     true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite                             boolean     true
d-i partman-auto/method                                     string      crypto
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase                               password    Trax2020
d-i partman-crypto/passphrase-again                         password    Trax2020
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size                            string      max

# grub boot loader
d-i grub-installer/only_debian                              boolean     true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os                            boolean     true
```

Images:

https://ibb.co/6RW5qrZ

https://ibb.co/x5rk2W2

(the images are more than 2M, so I can't upload it to here)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313899/how-to-create-an-unattended-install-of-ubuntu-mate-20-04

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the exact debconf option that is causing user interaction then add `DEBCONF_DEBUG=5` to the kernel boot parameters.  [This will cause debconf to print much more detail about the current settings of each variable and about its progress through each package's installation scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs05.html).  The debconf logs will be in the installer `syslog` file and printed on the `Alt-F4` terminal.

When the installer stops to prompt you, hit `Alt-F4` (use `Alt-F1` to get back to the main installer terminal) and the missing setting should be printed at the bottom of the screen and look something like

```
debconf: --> GET partman-partitioning/default_label
```

If I had to guess, you might be missing a label option.  My preseed includes these

```
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
```

#### Links

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters
- https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/get-the-debianubuntu-ready-and-customized-the-way-you-like-in-10-minutes/
- https://mraw.org/blog/2012/12/23/d-i_hacking_recipe_3/

Comment: Hey Andrew Lowther, I tried to do it but when I click Alt-F4 after I choose "YES" I don't see any "GET" or some log.....

Comment: I added some links with more explicit instructions that might be useful

Comment: I still can't get it works with nmve or with ssd 2.5