# Converting 300 physical centOS 7 servers(appliances) to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, migration

As centOS is going out of support, we are in the process of migrating all our centOs physical servers to Ubuntu 22.04 servers. These servers are distributed over various office locations.

As we have close to 300 centOS servers, I'm looking for options that will reduce the manual effort to physically perform the manual installation of Ubuntu on each of these. Is there an option like we could load the Ubunut OS on all of these servers remotely via some scripts?

Basically, trying to figure out if there is an option of auto install over the network where we can convert centOS server to Ubuntu server and restore the network settings so that the Ubuntu server is available on the newtwork?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Also see https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

Comment: If possible I  would ditch the local servers and convert to a cloud server. You could do with a cloud server and have everyone use that 1 server.  "where we can convert centOS server to Ubuntu server" No, this will require a reinstall.