# Boot from USB, setup through ssh

Tags: installation, server, usb, ssh

I've got a new home server with no keyboard, monitor, etc., but with the ability to boot from USB. I want to install Ubuntu Server on it, but can't work out how. If possible, I want a disk image that I can write to a USB drive to boot from which connects to the network and launches the ssh server, so that I can connect from my laptop and run setup from there.

Is this possible? What do I need to do?

Comment: See [How can I install Ubuntu on a device without a screen nor a keyboard?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250869/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-device-without-a-screen-nor-a-keyboard).