# how can I connect Ubuntu through Windows via localhost?

Tags: putty

Display of my laptop is not working, in order to save files in it I want to connect to it from another laptop in localhost and move files to safety. I can connect to it via putty from XP laptop like 192.168.2.5 and it successfully connects but I need a visual connection. Please don't suggest plugging another monitor or installing Ubuntu beside XP to establish visual connection.

What is the easiest way to establish visual connection between XP and Ubuntu?

Comment: "another laptop in localhost"? localhost will be always the system you are currently working. You can't connect another system localhost because... it will be the localhost of your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use putty to instal XRDP (`sudo apt-get install xrdp`) and connect to it via Remote Desktop from your windows machine.

obs: you can also try to use X11 forwarding in putty but you will need to have X11 on your windows machine (cygwin or others).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.
Exchange the HDD and then turn ON the computer. You will be able to boot Ubuntu and then perform all backup. I've tried it and its works perfectly :) You can put back the original HDD after taking backup.