# Installing Ubuntu On HP N54L headless

Tags: system-installation

I have a few question will try and be really precise and to the point.

1. I have ordered the N54L micro server by HP yet to be delivered.
2. I have read to install any OS I need to connect it to monitor via VGA and have to connect keyboard and mouse.
3. I do not want to either buy a monitor nor keyboard or mouse.
4. I have access to Macbook Air with VMWare fusion and 2 external hard disk.

Can I:

1. Install Ubuntu LTS as a virtual machine on my Macbook air.
2. Clone the Virtual Machine image onto the external hard disk.
3. Plug the hard disk into the N54L and then configure it using SSH.
4. Or just configure the Virtual Machine to my liking and then clone.

If all the can I's are possible would anyone be kind enough to guide me through this yet to become painful process.

I call it painful as I am not great with Linux but want to get familiar with it so am going to take on this task.

Comment: Please also check http://askubuntu.com/questions/250869/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-device-without-a-screen-nor-a-keyboard and http://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is technically possible, it would be very unstable. When you install Ubuntu, one of the steps is configuring itself for your particular hardware. Therefore, it would be configured to run on your virtual machine, not your server. It would be possible to run Ubuntu in an identical virtual machine in your server, but that would require keyboard and mouse access.

In short, it is possible, but very unstable. As a result, it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Simply put i should either get the stated equipment that i do not want to get as i will only really use them to set the server up. and avoid all the heartache.?

Comment: Yes, unless you are a very good Linux engineer, and are willing to risk several hours recovering your system.