# Install custom Ubuntu iso from network card

Tags: system-installation, ssh, iso, remote, pxe

I have a few customized Ubuntu ISOs (based in Ubuntu 12.04) that I need to install in a SBC embedded in an enclosure. Until now, I have to open the enclosure, connect a screen, keyboard and a USB installer every time the ISO needs updated. The user needs to manually introduce data during the installation.

I was hoping to use the network card to install the ISO.

I've read the [Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation). In my situation, without a keyboard or screen, I think the installation over ssh is the only available solution. However, it's a very manual process and I would have to redo lots of configuration and packing done to create the ISOs.

Is there a way to run a PXE server and run the installation from it like I was using ssh -X to forward the screen?

Any pointers to a solution are welcome, including the use of additional hardware.

I had partial success with [FOG](https://fogproject.org/). I can clone and restore the system using the network card only. I can also add an ISO image as part of the boot menu. I couldn't get the right settings to automatically boot from it, accept my custom preseed file and then use a kickstart file for the rest of the questions that my preseed is still going to ask.

**Edit**: A similar question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250869/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-device-without-a-screen-nor-a-keyboard/260469#260469). The main difference is that I don't have access to serial or USB ports, therefore the currently accepted answer is not valid for me. I do have a working installation from the first deployment and an ssh installation is possible in my system. I was hoping for something automated to avoid mistakes. Using my existing ISO files and ideally, something that someone with no experience in Linux could do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu on a device without a screen nor a keyboard?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250869/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-device-without-a-screen-nor-a-keyboard)

Comment: @Sneetsher the situations are different. I don't have access to USB or serial ports needed for the accepted answer. I explained that a completely unattended installation wasn't possible (second answer of that question). I do have a working installation because I have full access to the device the first time before is embedded.

Comment: I couldn't get why Jay's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/260469/26246 won't work (pxe boot+ preseed base system + ssh, then continue installing the remaining). Could you update the question and include that with reference to other question (so reviewers notice that)?

Comment: Sneetsher is talking about the 3rd answer there which seems to be exactly what you need. Have you tried that? Unless you confirm that it doesn't answer your question, I'll refund your bounty and close as a dupe.

Comment: Installation over ssh is indeed an option. I do mention this in my question.  The problem with this solution is that is very manual, easy to make mistakes and it doesn't use an ISO. The person making the installation has to extract, ssh and make the installation, assuming that there is enough hard drive to do this. I was hoping for an easier method, otherwise, people who are not trained in Linux prefer to open the enclosure and connect a cd, screen and keyboard rather than fighting with an ssh installation. If I can't find a better option, I will try to write a script for the ssh install.

Comment: OK, then please [edit] your question and explain why the other answer doesn't work for you. Otherwise, people are likely to ignore this assuming you just haven't read the other solutions.

Comment: Sneetsher asked me the same thing and I already edited the question and added `an ssh installation is possible in my system`.  In any  case the initial question also says `I think the installation over ssh is the only available solution`. I don't think a third time is needed. In a different note, the fact that other questions might have answers that are also valid for my question doesn't make my question a duplicate.

Comment: @katutxakurra, As I'm trying to understand (1) this case have some restriction unusual restriction no keyboard, no mouse, no screen, no usb, ONLY network. (2) you are trying give us the idea, NOT to start from base system  or official released iso or images. Why? you put much time to prepare some custom iso images that you want to make use of them instead of starting over (avoid to redo the job, may be you have to do setup for multiple SBC or quite routine task) (3) you had two trial with FOG, 1st through imaging (works), 2nd using iso netboot (failed to get preseed & ks working)..

Comment: Does this summarize the question? What is wrong/disadvantage of using FOG imaging? You mention ssh/X forward , is the prepared ISO customized from  live CD's, alternative desktop CD (with debian-installer , no gui), or server CD ?

Answer (score 0):

PXE is the way to go here , however your device will need to support network booting and have that enabled in the BIOS. Most devices with built in ethernet can do it now but some of the cheaper versions have it disabled.

There are instructions on setting up your PXE environemnt here, its quite involved and tricky to test so i won't both paraphrasing them here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

however that site seems to have problems at the moment so here is the google cached version of that page.

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:V2iecgLFBSEJ:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=ubuntu

Comment: This doesn't tell him how to do a full installation over the network without keyboard and mouse.  This just tells him how to boot into a network distro  - and even at that, he'd probably need a keyboard for that.

Comment: you don't need a keyboard or mouse for PXE once you have enabled PXE booting

Comment: No, but he will need it to complete the installation.

Comment: That is correct, this answer requires me to connect a keyboard to complete the custom iso installation.

Comment: it does exactly tell you how to do a full install over the network headlessly , if you use the debbootstrap method and read the linked page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/OnNFSDrive) you can just switch the the debian netboot image for an ubuntu desktop image. PXE can now serve up the entire CD to the client which (with enough RAM) will slurp it up and install super quick  from memory to the hard disk. Summarising the info in those pages wouldn't help anyone