# Installing Ubuntu without screen

Tags: system-installation, screen, remote

I have a laptop with a broken screen, but I have physical access to it. I also don't have any HDMI capable screen available.

My question is, how can I install Ubuntu without any screen?

Would it be possible somehow to connect another computer or a smartphone e.g. via USB to the laptop to control the installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu on a device without a screen nor a keyboard?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250869/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-device-without-a-screen-nor-a-keyboard) or [How do I create a completely unattended install of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-a-completely-unattended-install-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Couldn't you use a HDMI to DVI adapter, or a HDMI to VGA adapter?  They are not expensive and a quick Google search will turn them up.

Comment: The problem is that i do not have any available monitor at all, i have another laptop and smartphones

Comment: @БлаговестТодоров No TV screen?

Comment: I have an old TV with SCART